# How to change index fill factor and rebuild it using Migration Scripts?

Tags: entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm considering using Migration Scripts more and I'm looking for a native way to change an existing index fill factor and rebuild the index using Migration Scripts (I know I could use the .Sql method to inject some raw SQL),

I do not see any option to do that using the Migration Scripts .[CreateIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.createindex?view=efcore-3.1) method.

(please don't tell me that this is also a database-specific feature like having all the GUIDs converted to strings - I might get seriously disappointed, as Entity Framework should have a fully functional SQL Server provider by now)

Comment: This is coming with EF Core 5 - [Specify SQL Server index fill factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#specify-sql-server-index-fill-factor). Until then, well, you know, there is not much you can  do when something is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in the current version of Entity Framework.